# Why are these deep in-the-money FLEX options seemingly bought at a discount?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, option-strategies, european-options

[image: SPY Initial Reference Value]

[image: Purchased Call Options]

98% of the initial reference value is .98 x 267.88 dollars, which equals ***262.52 dollars***. However, the market value of each call contract they purchase is ***247.42 dollars***.

*How are they purchasing these call options at a discount?*

Here's the link to the prospectus (the reference value is on page 8, and the options price is on page 21): https://mplusfunds.com/defined-preservation-95-fund-fact-sheet-standard/prospectus-alaia-series-7-1-defined-preservation-95-fund-10-31-18/

Answer (score 4):

SPY pays dividends ~1.8%, and the expiry is ~3y (as of date was 2018, 2021 expiry), so the it looks like there is a discount

- Assuming $0 time value

$$OptionValue=Intrinsic Value+Time Value $$
$$OptionValue= (S-K)-Dividend$$
$$OptionValue=267x(1-0.02)-267x1.8\%x3=\\\$247$$

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reference value is, well, only for reference and not the real price.

Maybe the price of SPY when the call contract is bought is lower